# Usage of "it" pronoun for animals

Tags: pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of “it” and “its” for people and animals](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49404/use-of-it-and-its-for-people-and-animals)

I’m an Italian working in an English-speaking company. In school here they usually teach us to refer to animals using the *it* pronoun. Something like (i.e. talking about a dog):

> It’s really nice.

I see many people using *he* or *she* also for animals. What’s the correct way to use *it*? Should I use it only for inanimate things?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of "it" and "its" for people and animals](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49404/use-of-it-and-its-for-people-and-animals); also see linked questions   [1](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23541)  [2](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74161)  [3](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56567)  [4](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74647)  [5](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81137)

Comment: Also questions [6](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1059)  [7](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21185)  [8](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3178)  [9](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28618)  [10](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66422)

Comment: @tchrist, feel free to fix all of them!

Comment: @Napolux, Who is your audience for what you're writing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know a creature’s gender, you use *he* or *she*.  If you don’t, then you use *it*.  Sometimes this is useful for disambiguating.

> A cow produces milk for **her** calf, but people drink it, too.
>
> That rooster’s infernal cockle-doodle-do is going to get **him** consigned to the soup pot.
>
> A hen won’t lay eggs if **she** doesn’t have a rooster around.
>
> My garbage was dumped over by a mother bear and **her** two cubs two nights ago.
>
> The bull moose appeared right in the middle of my path, so I had to go around **him**.

In all those cases, the gender of the critters is a given, so it makes sense — and is useful — to use a gendered pronoun to refer to them.  Notice how in the first sentence, if you replace *her* with *its*, things begin to sound weird and ambiguous.

Comment: One other comment: if you don't know the creature's gender, you can use either _him_ or _her_ in place of _it_. For example: _The neighbor's cat was meowing at the door, so I put out a saucer of milk for her_. Or: _That squirrel ran right out in front of my bike! I almost hit him!_ Generally speaking, people don't get up in arms if you happen to use a wrong-gendered pronoun when talking about an animal, particularly when the correct gender isn't known for certain.